# IntelliJ Idea: Align on Colon for Scala Case Class Members?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, code-formatting, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to prevent Idea from reformatting multiline case class members?

**Intended** result
(position of the colon is not so important, but the alignment of the type annotations would be great)

```scala
case class ApiError(
  timestamp : LocalDateTime,
  status    : Int,
  code      : Option[String],
  message   : String
)
```

I've spent some time in the Code Styling settings for Scala and am stuck with code styling like this:

```scala
case class ApiError(
  timestamp: LocalDateTime,
  status: Int,
  code: Option[String],
  message: String
)
```

I am okay with cluttering the code with `@formatter:off`, but it would be awesome if there was a better way.

Comment: Side note: Consider if you _really_ want this. Once you have your code formatted like this, and you add a new member whose name is longer than the other ones, you will see _all the lines_ changed in the VCS history - even though in reality only one member was added. Why make the formatting of a line so dependent on other, unrelated lines? - On top of that, you set it in stone that your code can only be viewed properly with a fixed width font. Again, why? Your desired formatting makes it easier to get an overview over the types used for members, but harder to see which member has which type.

Comment: @Madoc I agree about the downside in combination with VC. At the moment the visual decluttering (which is highly subjective, of course) justifies that for me (I did it in a similar way in the past two JS projects and started to like the way it structures the code). To be precise, I wouldn't necessarily expect Idea to provide it as an auto-formatting option, but rather as a **Keep when reformatting**-type of setting.

Comment: Sure, it was just an opinion. Personally, I turned of automated code formatting for Scala code. For Java code, I still leave it on.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Madoc commented, those kind of formats may lead to huge changes when adding a new line. Also, while pretty in small cases, it doesn't scale, and it seems we are programming in tables...

Answer (score 0):

my IntelliJ IDEA version is ultimate 2019.3

step 1. Prefrences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scala

[image: scalas]

step 2. Wrapping and Braces -> Method declaration parameters, then
check "Align paramenter types in multiline declarations"

[image: declaration]

I tried the example in question, it was

```
case class ApiError(
                     timestamp: LocalDateTime,
                     status   : Int,
                     code     : Option[String],
                     message  : String
                   )
```

if you uncheck "Align when multiline", it is consistent with intended result.

[image: Align when multiline]

```
case class ApiError(
  timestamp: LocalDateTime,
  status   : Int,
  code     : Option[String],
  message  : String
)
```